# Multiple JQuery Datepicker with hidden input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm using a variable number of datepicker on my page.

Every datepicker must be always visible and I don't want to display the input field.

```
foreach ($array as $k =>$z) {
  echo "<div id='datepicker".$k."'></div>
        <input name='dates[]' id='datepicker_input".$k."' type='hidden' >";
}
```

javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 <?php
      foreach ($array as $k => $z) {
          echo "$('#datepicker".$k."').datetimepicker({      
              format:'d.m.Y H:i',
              inline:true,
              lang:'en'
          });";
      }
 ?>
});
</script>
```

My Goal is to send all the dates using a form, so that when I click to my submit button I can retrieve every dates from _POST.
Unfortunately, the dates array I retrieve contains empty arrays.

I dont know how to bind the datepicker inline with my hidden fields...
I need to update the hidden input fields with the selected values.

Maybe I'll have to use JSON, but I'm not sure of what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Try something like this `<input name='dates[".$k."]' id='datepicker".$k."' type='hidden'>` and after send try debugging with `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: My only issue here is that I don't know how to bind the datepicker inline with my hidden fields

Comment: You can't use the same id twice. Div or input, not both. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pms2juab/3/

HTML:

```
<input name='dates[]' id='datepicker1' class="datepicker" type='hidden' />
<input name='dates[]' id='datepicker2' class="datepicker" type='hidden' />
<input name='dates[]' id='datepicker3' class="datepicker" type='hidden' />
<input name='dates[]' id='datepicker4' class="datepicker" type='hidden' />
<input name='dates[]' id='datepicker5' class="datepicker" type='hidden' />
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
   $('.datepicker').each(function(i,k){
   $(this).datetimepicker({      
              format:'d.m.Y H:i',
              inline:true,
              lang:'en'
          });
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, its cleaner that what I've found

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 <?php
      foreach ($array as $k => $z) {
          echo "$('#datepicker".$k."').datetimepicker({      
              format:'d.m.Y H:i',
              inline:true,
              lang:'en'
          });

             $('#datepicker_input".$k."').change(function(){
                $('#datepicker".$k."').datepicker('setDate', $(this).val());
             });
             $('#datepicker".$k."').change(function(){
                $('#datepicker_input".$k."').attr('value',$(this).val());
             });
      }
 ?>
});
</script>
```